# decalring jquery function inside function

Tags: jquery

can I make a function to feed to a jQuery function?

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button1").attr("src","img.png")
});
```

to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
foo('button1','img.png')
    });

function foo(objname,imurl)
{
    $(objname).attr("src",imurl)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. But on your example there is no `#` for id And no `.` for class on your selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    foo('#button1','img.png');
});

function foo(objname,imurl)
{
    $(objname).attr("src",imurl)
}
```

---

**Second option:** If you are planning to pass an `ID` **only**, You can:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    foo('button1','img.png');
});

function foo(objID,imurl)
{
    $( "#" + objID ).attr("src",imurl)
}
```